# How to Show Some Columns as comma separated in a report using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have  4 tables like :
1) tbl_subjects

```
      +----+------+-------------------+
      | id | C_Id |     subject       |
      +----+------+-------------------+
      |  1 |   13 | తెలుగు             |
      |  2 |   13 | हिन्दी              |
      |  3 |   13 | ENGLISH           |
      |  4 |   13 | MATHEMATICS       |
      |  5 |   13 | PHYSICAL SCIENCES |
      |  6 |   13 | BIOLOGY           |
      |  7 |   13 | SOCIAL STUDIES    |
      +----+------+-------------------+
```

2) tbl_masterexam

```
      +------+-----+--------------------+
      | exid | Cid |        exnm        |
      +------+-----+--------------------+
      |   64 |  13 | Unit Test-1        |
      |   65 |  13 | Unit Test-2        |
      |   66 |  13 | Quarterly Exams    |
      |   67 |  13 | Unit Test-3        |
      |   68 |  13 | Half yearly Exams  |
      |   69 |  13 | Unit Test-4        |
      |   70 |  13 | Pre - Public Exams |
      +------+-----+--------------------+
```

3) tbl_cmarks

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Cid | Examid | rollno | subId | Marks | paper |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     3 |    21 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     1 |    18 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     2 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     4 |    23 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     5 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     6 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     7 |    22 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     3 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     1 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     2 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     4 |    22 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     5 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     6 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     1 |    75 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     2 |    89 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     4 |    80 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     5 |    45 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     6 |    42 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     7 |    89 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     3 |    41 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     3 |    35 |     3 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     4 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     4 |    45 |     3 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     3 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     3 |    41 |     3 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     3 |    16 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     1 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     4 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     5 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     6 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     1 |    45 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     1 |    40 |     3 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     2 |    75 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     5 |    40 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     6 |    42 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     7 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     7 |    40 |     3 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     3 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     1 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     2 |    18 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     4 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     5 |    12 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     6 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     7 |    15 |     1 |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

4) tbl_exam

```
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
     | class | sid | paper | MaM | ExId |
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   64 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   64 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   65 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   65 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   3 |     2 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   67 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   67 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   3 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   3 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   1 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   1 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 | 100 |   68 |
     |    13 |   4 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   4 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   7 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   7 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   69 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   69 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   3 |     3 |  50 |   66 |
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
```

I have written a sql code to generate an output like this:

```
SELECT 
ts.subject as 'SUBJECT',
tme.exnm as 'EXAM',
tc.Marks as 'MARKS',
tc.paper as 'PAPER'
FROM
tbl_cmarks tc,
tbl_subjects ts,
tbl_masterexam tme
WHERE tc.rollno = 1 AND 
ts.id = tc.subId AND 
tme.exid = tc.Examid
```

It Produces an output Like this :

```
      +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
      |      SUBJECT      |       EXAM        | MARKS | PAPER |
      +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
      | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-1       |    21 |     1 |
      | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-1       |    18 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-1       |    20 |     1 |
      | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-1       |    23 |     1 |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-1       |    11 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-1       |    11 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-1       |    22 |     1 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-2       |    19 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-2       |    22 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-2       |    10 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-2       |    10 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Quarterly Exams   |    75 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Quarterly Exams   |    89 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Quarterly Exams   |    80 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Quarterly Exams   |    45 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Quarterly Exams   |    42 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Quarterly Exams   |    89 |     1 |
       | ENGLISH           | Half yearly Exams |    41 |     2 |
       | ENGLISH           | Half yearly Exams |    35 |     3 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     2 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Half yearly Exams |    45 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Quarterly Exams   |    40 |     2 |
       | ENGLISH           | Quarterly Exams   |    41 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-3       |    16 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-3       |    19 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-3       |    20 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-3       |    10 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-3       |    10 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-3       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Half yearly Exams |    45 |     2 |
       | తెలుగు            | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     3 |
       | हिन्दी            | Half yearly Exams |    75 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Half yearly Exams |    42 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     2 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-4       |    19 |     1 |
        | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-4       |    19 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-4       |    18 |     1 |
      | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-4       |    20 |     1 |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-4       |    12 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-4       |    11 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-4       |    15 |     1 |
       +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

But I want to Display the result as :

```
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
      |                   |  U.T-1  |  U.T-2  |  Quart  |  U.T-3  |  Half   | U.T-4   |
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
      | SUBJECT           | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G |
      | ENGLISH         | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 40,45 50,50 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      |  తెలుగు           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      |  हिन्दी           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | MATHEMATICS       | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | BIOLOGY           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | SOCIAL STUDIES    | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Please anyone tell me where should i change my query to reproduce the desired result

I have tried GROUP_CONCAT(exnm) But i am not able to get the desired result.
Please tell me / give me an idea to write the code to display like this.

Thank you.

To Display the Grade i have created a Function like this

```
      DELIMITER $$
      CREATE FUNCTION `ShowGrade`(val FLOAT(10,2)) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
      BEGIN
      DEClARE p FLOAT(10,2);    
      DEClARE g TEXT;
      set p=val;
  IF p>=91 and p<=100 THEN 
    set g= "A+";
  END IF;
  IF p>=71 and p<=90 THEN 
        set g= "A";
    END IF;
  IF p>=51 and p<=70 THEN 
    set g= "B+";
    END IF;
  IF p>=41 and p<=50 THEN 
    set g= "B";
    END IF;
  IF p>=0 and p<=40 THEN 
    set g= "C";
    END IF;
      return g;
     END
```

AND Finally I have written a sql code to show some part result.

```
      set session group_concat_max_len= 100000;
      SET @sql = NULL;
      SET @sql1=NULL;
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                           CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,
                           ''' and m.paper=1 THEN marks END) `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-1'), '`,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,''' and m.paper=2   THEN marks END)  `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-2'), '`,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,''' and m.paper=3  THEN marks END) `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-3'), '`'))
       INTO @sql FROM tbl_masterexam WHERE cid = 13;

     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
          CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,''' and te.paper=1 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-1'), '`,
          MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,
                     ''' and te.paper=2 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-2'), '`,
            MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,
                     ''' and te.paper=3 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(exnm,'p-3'), '`'))
    INTO @sql1
    FROM tbl_exam te JOIN tbl_masterexam tme On tme.exid=te.ExId
    WHERE te.class = 13 AND tme.Cid=13;

      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.subject,', @sql,',',@sql1,'
         FROM tbl_cmarks m JOIN tbl_subjects s ON m.subid = s.id 
                   JOIN tbl_exam te On te.sid = s.id AND  te.ExId=m.Examid  WHERE m.rollno = 1 AND m.cid = 13 AND te.class=13 GROUP BY  m.subid,s.subject');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

By executing the above code i'm able to fetch the Marks correctly but MaM(Max Marks) Column Values are repeating 7 times each, and also i want to show the result of P-1,P-2,P-3 as in single column by comma separating, Like as shown above in the desired Result.

Could anyone please help me/ give me a hint to  show the result exactly what i'm expecting.

Comment: ORDER BY subject. Then handle the display logic at the application level/presentation layer, assuming there is one (e.g. a simple php loop)

Comment: If you can provide sample on [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Oh sure, here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb17c/4 plz look at this script

Comment: @Strawberry- Is this not possible from pure sql script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that i am too late, so sorry if i am.
But I think it can be like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len= 100000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql1=NULL;
SET @sql2='1=1';

SET @create_sql=NULL;
SET @create_sql1=NULL;

select distinct group_concat(distinct concat(
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p1 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL',','),
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p2 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL',','),
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p3 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL')))
INTO @create_sql
FROM tbl_masterexam
 WHERE cid = 13;

select group_concat(distinct concat( 
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p11 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL',','),
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p21 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL',','),
               CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p31 INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL')))
INTO @create_sql1
  FROM tbl_exam te 
right JOIN tbl_masterexam tme ON tme.exid=te.ExId
 #WHERE te.class = 13 AND tme.Cid=13;

PREPARE stmt0 FROM 'drop temporary table if exists temp_masterexam; ';
EXECUTE stmt0;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt0;

select concat('create temporary table temp_masterexam(
                subject VARCHAR( 17 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,',
              @create_sql,',',@create_sql1,
              ');')
INTO @create_sql;

#select @create_sql;


PREPARE stmt FROM @create_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;



SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,
         ''' and m.paper=1 THEN marks END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p1'), '`,
                MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,
                         ''' and m.paper=2 THEN marks END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p2'), '`,
                MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,
                         ''' and m.paper=3 THEN marks END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p3'), '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM tbl_masterexam
 WHERE cid = 13;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         distinct CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,
         ''' and te.paper=1 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p11'), '`,
                MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,
                         ''' and te.paper=2 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p21'), '`,
                MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', te.exid,
                         ''' and te.paper=3 THEN MaM END) `',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p31'), '`'))
INTO @sql1
  FROM tbl_exam te 
JOIN tbl_masterexam tme ON tme.exid=te.ExId
 WHERE te.class = 13 AND tme.Cid=13;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         distinct CONCAT('null ',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p11'), ',',
                         'null ',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p21'), ',',
                         'null ',CONCAT(acronym(exnm),'p31'), ''))
INTO @sql2
  FROM tbl_exam te 
right JOIN tbl_masterexam tme ON tme.exid=te.ExId
where te.ExId is null;

#
SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into temp_masterexam ','SELECT s.subject,', @sql,',',@sql1,',',@sql2,'
                    FROM tbl_cmarks m JOIN tbl_subjects s
                       ON m.subid = s.id
                        JOIN tbl_exam te ON te.sid = s.id AND te.ExId=m.Examid
                    WHERE m.rollno = 1
                      AND m.cid = 13
                      AND te.class=13
                    GROUP BY m.subid,s.subject');
#select @sql;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

#select subject,concat(IFNULL(UT1P1,''),',',IFNULL(UT1P2,''),',',IFNULL(UT1P3,'')) from temp_masterexam 
#select * from temp_masterexam ;
select group_concat(concat("concat(
                            IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p1"),",0),',',",
                           "IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p2"),",0),',',",
                           "IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p3"),",0),' ',",
                           "IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p11"),",0),',',",
                           "IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p21"),",0),',',",
                           "IFNULL(",CONCAT(acronym(exnm),"p31"),",0)) ",acronym(exnm)))
INTO @sql
FROM tbl_masterexam
 WHERE cid = 13;
#select @sql;

set @sql=concat('select subject,',@sql,' from temp_masterexam');


PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
```

But, with my code:
1. There is no grade, because i do not know what mark should be used for it.
2. The output not like you wanted, when there is no data there is 0 not empty.

You can look at the script live:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23cd9/134
I think if was in your place i would done this partially with server script(PHP for example).

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrej. Your Code is perfectly working.  But i have completed this task using PHP. Anyway thanks for replying to my post.